# Gsub AWK case insensitive

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, gsub

on AIX

```
sed  's/foo/bar/gwi'
```

file does not work

My AIX does not like w and i flags. w is to write to the file itself and i for insensitive search
I know I did this long ago- but I am lazy but still wanted to keep this in my drawer. How can I replace

- 1st or Nth occurrence of foo with bar in file and write it directly to the file NOT to std o/p
- ALL occurrences in case INSENSITIVE manner of foo with bar - to the SAME file not std o/p
- I can have MULTIPLE i/p files not just one

This works for ALL and writes to std o/p. I want it to MODIFY  same file and just spit out lines where replacements were made ( split out lines to Std o/p to confirm whatever it did but write directly to file )

```
awk 'IGNORECASE = 1{ gsub(/foo/,"bar")} 1 ' ipfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `IGNORECASE`, it appears you have GNU awk. GNU awk
can also utilize `@include` mechanism:

```
awk '@include "/usr/share/awk/inplace.awk"; program' file
```

Or

```
awk --include=/usr/share/awk/inplace.awk 'program' file
```

Or

```
awk '@include "inplace"; program' file
```

Or

```
awk -iinplace 'program' file
```

Comment: Ignore case does not work for some reason. Not sure whats happening

Comment: I have  very ltd priv. on AIX. The above `iinplace` parameter and the path both are non existent for my awk.  ( Its one of those awkward awk  ! )  . Thanks for wanting to help`awk: Not a recognized flag: i
Usage: awk [-u] [-F Character][-v Variable=Value][-f File|Commands][Variable=Value|File ...]`